# React : Async - Select drop down - JSON object trouble

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using the Async - React Select drop down in react - https://react-select.com/async
The dataset for the drop down needs to look like this :

```
async function getPromise4(): Promise<Person[]> {

  return [
    {
      value: 'Tom',
      label: 'Tom',
    },
    {
      value: 'David',
      label: 'David',
    },
    {
      value: 'MeeMee',
      label: 'MeeMee',
    },
  ];
}
```

and I am trying to get this created from an API. The API works ok but it doesn't give it back as value / label - so I cannot return the data direct to the drop down by a promise.

I am struggling to create an object like about. This is the code I use to get the data from the API.

```
async function main(): Promise<void> {
  const foo = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]).then(function (stuff) {
    var records = stuff.value
    records.forEach(function (value) {
      console.log(value.name);
```

This above code gets the data from the API fine. I guess I need to iterate over the data and build an object like above. I am sure its quite reasonable to do but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Are you just asking how to transform returned API data into an object? Do we need to know all the other stuff if that's all you're asking? You also never showed us what data the API returns. Please be more concise with your questions and include the relevant information.